# Design Time viewing for User Control events

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've create a WinForms control that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl...I've got some custom events on the control that I would like the consumer of my control to be able to see. I'm unable to actually get my events to show up in the Events tab of the Properties window during design time. This means the only way to assign the events is to programmatically write

```
myUserControl.MyCustomEvent += new MyUserControl.MyCustomEventHandler(EventHandlerFunction);
```

this is fine for me I guess but when someone else comes to use my UserControl they are not going to know that these events exist (unless they read the library doco...yeah right). I know the event will show up using Intellisense but it would be great if it could show in the properties window too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure your events are exposed as public. For example...

```
[Browsable(true)]
public event EventHandler MyCustomEvent;
```

Comment: It's a public custom event handler and the event handler type is a public delegate...there is nothing functionally wrong...the events work and fire in the correct way, it's purely a design time issue.

Comment: Aha, make sure the event handler definition is always declared as public otherwise it will not be visible.

Comment: I've also just changed it from my custom event handler type to a simple EventHandler and it still doesn't show in the Events tab of Properties Window

Comment: I've update the answer to show the extra browser attribute you can try

Answer (score 0):

A solution using delegate. For example i used for a custom ListView which handle item added event : 
Declare your delegate :

```
   public delegate void ItemAddedHandler(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
```

then declare the event which use the delegate :

```
   [Browsable(true)]
   public event ItemAddedHandler ItemAdded;
```

Note : ItemEventArgs is a custom EventArgs

Hope can help you, works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem many times!
It depends on the data you want in your event.
So if you just want to be informed, then a delegate that's an Action will work just fine.

```
public event Action SomethingHappened;
```

If you want the event to have a payload that is of a primitive type, then this should work too.

```
public event Action<int> LengthChanged;
```

The moment you want things to get more complicated it might not work. For example, this WON'T work.

```
public event Action<byte?> WidgetChanged;
```

why? Because its nullable?  Yeah, I would say that's a fair observation.  The editor goes back to C# 1.0 onwards, and that level of development didn't have generics.
But wait - isn't an Action generic?  Yes it is!  But the payload of the event is not. (int)

How then to get over this limitation?
You just need to define your own delegate, oddly.
For example:

```
public delegate void CustomerLeavingDelegate(bool? sentiment);
public event CustomerLeavingDelegate CustomerLeaving;
```